# how to create netbeans project in cammandline?

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm currently developing a extension for easily open online java files in net-beans.let's say there is a source code starting `package examplename` then i want to make a project named examplename .so i can handle browser side codes.and extension opens a java program then java programe find package name ,class name .so the problem is how can a java program create a specific net-beans package and make a class programically.if there is command line option i can handle it ...

i can open a file in netbeans using this command .but only open file not create any package or file .

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.1\\bin\\netbeans64.exe", my.java);
pb.start();
```

thanks

Comment: There might be several kind of projects. I'd start looking on the available archetypes of `maven-archetype-plugin` for Maven.

Comment: @rlegendi actually i have heared about maven but i don't know it.i'm looking for creating java project

Comment: Check this 5 min tutorial, it starts with creating a project with Maven: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html NB has tons of different project layouts, but it can create from Maven archetypes too.

Comment: @rlegendi thanks you .i will definitely learn it

Comment: Ok. Just to clarify things: I don't say NB does it that way, but it has a wizard to create projects from Maven archetypes. Also, check the existing archetypes, maybe you can find a way to create a NB project from the command line.